# error C2783 Could not deduce template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I am stuck with this error . **I have found a workaround too but it kind of kills the whole purpose of exercise.**

I am trying to create a function which will take two iterators pointing to same container . I will find the sum of elements between them. I created general function for the sequential containers like vector which works fine. I overloaded the same function for associative containers. This is the one giving error.

```
map<string,double> myMap;
myMap["B"]=1.0;
myMap["C"]=2.0;
myMap["S"]=3.0;
myMap["G"]=4.0;
myMap["P"]=5.0;

map<string,double>::const_iterator iter1=myMap.begin();
map<string,double>::const_iterator iter2=myMap.end();

cout<<"\nSum of map using the iterator specified range is: "<<Sum(iter1,iter2)<<"\n"; 
//Above line giving error. Intellisense is saying: Sum, Error: no instance of overloaded function "Sum" matches the argument list.

//function to calculate the sum is listed below (It appears in a header file with <map> header included):
template <typename T1,typename T2>
double Sum(const typename std::map<T1,T2>::const_iterator& input_begin,const typename std::map<T1,T2>::const_iterator& input_end)
{
double finalSum=0;
typename std::map<T1,T2>::const_iterator iter=input_begin;

for(iter; iter!=input_end; ++iter)
{
    finalSum=finalSum+ (iter)->second;
}

return finalSum;
}
```

Compilation error is:
1>c:\documents and settings\ABC\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\demo.cpp(41): error C2783: 'double Sum(const std::map::const_iterator &,const std::map::const_iterator &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T1'

**Workaround:**

If call Sum(iter1,iter2) is replaced with Sum < string,double > (iter1,iter2), it compiles fine.

Was I trying to do something impossible as per C++ standards in the first place?

Comment: Try making Sum's template types the iterator instead of the iterator's content's types.

Comment: Then it clashes with the general sum function I have written for vector and other sequential containers:

     template<typename T> 
     double Sum(const T& input_begin,const T& input_end)

Comment: Then specialize your generic sum for the specific iterator types here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is actually quite clear, in the following template:

```
template <typename T1,typename T2>
double Sum(const typename std::map<T1,T2>::const_iterator& input_begin,
           const typename std::map<T1,T2>::const_iterator& input_end)
```

The types `T1` and `T2` cannot be deduced from the argument at the place of call. This is defined as such in the standard and if you think about it (in the general case) it makes sense.

Consider that instead of `std::map<>::const_iterator` you had `sometemplate<T>::nested_type` and that the argument at the place of call was an `int`. If the compiler had to deduce the type, it would have to instantiate `sometemplate` for all possible types `T` in the universe (infinite set) and find for which of them the nested type `nested_type` is a typedef to `int`.

As someone points out in the comments you can change the template so that instead of being templated on the key and value types of the map it just takes the iterators.

---

**Delegating extraction of the value**

This is a workaround to providing a single implementation of `Sum` that can deal with both sequential and associative containers.

```
namespace detail {
template <typename T> T valueOf( T const & t ) { return t; }
template <typename K, typename V>
V valueOf( std::pair<const K, V> const & p ) {
   return p.second;
}
}
template <typename Iterator>
double Sum( Iterator begin, Iterator end ) {
  double result = 0;
  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
     result += detail::valueOf(*begin);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I have not tested the code, but that should do it. And this is probably much simpler than using SFINAE on the `Sum` template.

Comment: The set of all types is far from infinite and the compiler probably has a list of them. The problem is that each "indirection" like this multiplies the complexity by the number of types.

Comment: @Dani: The set of types **is** infinite once you have a template, consider just the basic type `int` and the container `std::vector` (ignore allocator types), you can have: `int`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ... and you can nest as many as you want yielding an infinite number of types from just one basic type and a template. As you say it also involves a nonlinear growth in complexity, but even linear would be intractable.

Comment: General sum function I have written for vector and other sequential containers is already templatized on iterators only. Just to handle the maps I wrote the overloaded version.
(My general function): 
template<typename T> double Sum(const T& input_begin,const T& input_end)

@Jason:
I have rewritten the sum function as a plain overloaded function, no templates. Was that what you meant? 

double Sum(const std::map<std::string,double>::const_iterator& input_begin,const std::map<std::string,double>::const_iterator& input_end)

It is working fine. Trying to understand the whole thing.

Comment: @CPlusPlus-Killing-me-softly: You can use SFINAE to provide a second function that is still only templated on the iterator and that will only be used if the iterator is an iterator to a map (or at least get close enough through a heuristic, as for example `value_type` being a `std::pair<T,U>`)

Comment: ... or alternatively you can delegate obtaining the value to a second function for which you have a template (specialization) that takes `std::pair<>`

Comment: I am new to all this. I will google on what "Substitution failure is not an error" is and try to implement it. Meanwhile I guess I will pass the paramters explicity like: Sum < string,double > (iter1,iter2)

Comment: @CPlusPlus-Killing-me-softly: You might find it easier delegating the extraction of the value. I am providing that as an edit.